# Get current Latitude and Longitude on Android

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get the current latitude and longitude on Android. I know that there are many questions and gudies for doint it, but almos all of them asked before many years.

I just want to get every time the user get into the activity his lat and lon, I don't need to update his location, just to get it once he gets into the app.

Is there an easy way to do so?

I can't find something simple as I want in the internet.

Comment: uhh, so what if they've been asked years ago? Have you tried them first and see if they work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the developer site that detailly explains to you how to do just that https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Getting the last known location of the user is so simple if you use the google location Api's.

**Step 1:** Build the Api Client in your Activity's onCreate().

**Step 2:** Connect and disconnect the Google APi Client in the onStart() and onStop().

**Step 3:** Use the Fused Location Api's getLastLocation method to get the last known location of the user inside the onConnected().

**Step 4:** Get the latitude and longitude values.

In addition to that, you can check out the [official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/BasicLocationSample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/basiclocationsample/MainActivity.java). If you still have doubts or have something that you don't understand, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code might help you.

```
    LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0.3f, new android.location.LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.d("location changed",location.getLatitude()+"-"+location.getLongitude());


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    });
```